# Request not getting formed properly

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

iam working on Jax-ws webservice, when i import wsdl to SoapUI, i see in request input object(tag) to the operation showing as `<arg0>`. How can replace this tag to my input object eg:`<myserviceVO>`
Below is request generated from wsdl .

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:processFaceDetection>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <imageName>?</imageName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <imageSrc>?</imageSrc>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <userEmail>?</userEmail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <userName>?</userName>
         </arg0>
      </ws:processFaceDetection>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**WSDL:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/" name="FaceDetectionV001Service">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/" schemaLocation="http://lenovo-pc:8989/facedetections/FaceDetection?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="insertImages">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:insertImages"/>
</message>
<message name="insertImagesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:insertImagesResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="processFaceDetection">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:processFaceDetection"/>
</message>
<message name="processFaceDetectionResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:processFaceDetectionResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="FaceDetection">
<operation name="insertImages">
<input wsam:Action="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/FaceDetection/insertImagesRequest" message="tns:insertImages"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/FaceDetection/insertImagesResponse" message="tns:insertImagesResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="processFaceDetection">
<input wsam:Action="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/FaceDetection/processFaceDetectionRequest" message="tns:processFaceDetection"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://ws.facedetection.facial.com/FaceDetection/processFaceDetectionResponse" message="tns:processFaceDetectionResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="FaceDetectionV001PortBinding" type="tns:FaceDetection">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="insertImages">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="processFaceDetection">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="FaceDetectionV001Service">
<port name="FaceDetectionV001Port" binding="tns:FaceDetectionV001PortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://lenovo-pc:8989/facedetections/FaceDetection"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Show us your wsdl. Also, don't post pastebin links. Post everything in your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i adde WSDL too, please can you check